# How to require a field if a checkbox is selected with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input, checkbox

I have a short form that needs some validation help. The current javascript requires each field to be completed...except for the telephone number. However, I'd like the telephone field be required IF someone selects to be contacted for a consultation. Hope my current work doesn't have to be thrown away. Any help would be great. Thanks!

**Javascript**:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

function validateForm(f)
{
    // If they entered an email address, then edit it before submitting the form

    // Require Email Address
    if (f. field_45042.value == '')
    {
        alert('Please enter your email address.')
        f. field_45042.focus()
        return false;
    } 

    // Require First Name
    if (f. field_57841.value == '')
    {
        alert('Please enter your first name.')
        f. field_57841.focus()
        return false;
    } 

    // Require Last Name
    if (f. field_57842.value == '')
    {
        alert('Please enter your last name.')
        f. field_57842.focus()
        return false;
    } 

    // Require Zip Code
    if (f. field_70761.value == '')
    {
        alert('Please enter your zip code.')
        f. field_70761.focus()
        return false;
    } 

    // Require Location
    if (f.field_70694[0].selected == true)
    {
        alert('Please select a store location.')
        f.field_70694.focus()
        return false;
    } 
}

// -->
</script>
```

**HTML**:

```
Email Address:<input type="text" id="field_45042" class="text_field" size="35" name="45042" value="" />
First Name:<input type="text" id="field_57841" class="text_field" size="35" name="45043[57841]" value="" />
Last Name:<input type="text" id="field_57842" class="text_field" size="35" name="45044[57842]" value="" />
Zip Code:<input type="text" id="field_70761" class="text_field" size="35" name="45045[70761]" value="" />
Telephone:<input type="text" id="field_62646" class="text_field" size="35" name="45046[62646]" value="" />

Preferred Store Location:
<select id="field_70694" class="select field" name="42714[70694]" >
    <option value="Select One of the Following:" >Select one of the following:</option>
    <option value="Store 1" >Store 1</option>
    <option value="Store 1" >Store 2</option>
    <option value="Store 1" >Store 3</option>
</select>

Please contact me for a FREE consultation.
<select id="field_71849" class="select field" name="45924[71849]" >
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No" >No</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
if (f.field_71849.value == "Yes" && f.field_62646.value == '') {

    alert('Please enter a phone number.')
    f.field_62646.focus()
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 // ...

 // require phone if wants to be contacted
 if(f.field_71849.value == 'Yes' && f.field_62646.value == ''){
   alert('Please enter your phone number');
   return false;
 }

 // ...
```